# netsh command to block URL from firewall

Tags: firewall, url, netsh

I am trying to block a URL with the firewall using netsh command, but without success. This is how I block an IP:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Block URL" remoteip=<ip_to_block> dir=out enable=yes action=block
```

It does not work by replacing the IP with the URL

Answer (score 1):

You need to Resolve the Urls IP.

You can use **nslookup** to do this or some other ip resolver.

Example

**http://www.tomshardware.com/**

[image]

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Block URL" remoteip=<194.25.95.137> dir=out enable=yes action=block
```

And

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Block URL" remoteip=<194.25.95.131> dir=out enable=yes action=block
```

Also you can use a website such as this to resolve the Ip of the URL.

[Website Resolver](http://www.hcidata.info/host2ip.htm)

Comment: That will work in a limited way. Example: you can't do that vs. big sites like facebook.

Comment: I Know, if you want to edit that and put and example in there you can @Overmind otherwise I can in a bit.

Comment: I tried before getting the ip using nslookup but I was getting "DNS request timed out" - this is a separate issue I was working to solve. But using the website resolver that NetworkKingPin provided worked for me. But as Overmind said, this is a limited way of blocking the URL, and it might not work everytime, also it would get dificult if ip's are changing often.